# Need script to deploy, undeploy apps and get list of installed apps

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

1. Is there any way to get list of installed CARs and reading meta-data (version, etc..) on wso2esb beside web-interface? I want to use it in jenkins script.
2. I found [jenkins plugin](https://github.com/ma-ha/Jenkins-WSO2-CAR-Deployer/) for deploying CARs. How can I remove some installed car?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot admin tasks using the OSGI web services.

To get a list of the service, start the server in OSGI console mode:

```
./wso2server.sh -DosgiConsole
```

After the server startup, you can list all available services:

```
osgi> listAdminServices
```

Now you see all URLs (endpoints) of the SOAP Services. It depends, what you deployed using the CAR, but I assume that you may use the "SynapseApplicationAdmin", "RestApiAdmin" or "ApplicationAdmin" service.

I've found the "ApplicationAdmin" WSDL here: https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/service-stubs/org.wso2.carbon.application.mgt.stub/src/main/resources/ApplicationAdmin.wsdl

In this service you can use operations, like

- listAllApplications
- deleteApplication